# Typescript: Mongodb promises

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

This feels like a common enough question, but I can't find it already asked. *What should be the Typescript signature* of the return value of the function below?

In practise, the right question is perhaps *which definitely typed file do I need*, as all the ones I looked at seemed to be defining the callback versions of mongo commands?

So far I have `tsd` installed node, mongodb and bluebird.

```
function countCountries(db) : *?????* {
    let register = db.collection(REGISTER);

    let countries = [an aggregate]

    return countries.toArray()
        .then( results => {
            return db.collection(SUMMARY)
                .replaceOne( {_id: COUNTRIES}, 
                             {_id: COUNTRIES, 'data': results}, 
                             {upsert: true}  );
        } );
}
```

I'm using Bluebird more generally in my code including as `Promise.promisify(mongoClient.connect);`, but here Typescript in inferring a Type of `Promise<{}>` whereas the promise actually returns a  database connection.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/coderfox/355d51b71c4072bcf9b3 claims to be `TypeScript definition files for bluebird promised MongoDB-native module` but I think you'll have to fix it a bit because `toArray()` method does not return a promise according to this `.d.ts` file. The proper place to look is https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/mongodb according to me. But there is not a variant for Bluebird.

Comment: These seem to be very similar, at least as regards the main methods on collections. I.e. the both refer to `callback?` functions and return `: void`, whereas I am looking to return a Promise (I'm not sure whether mongo's built in promises use Bluebird or something else). Hope I get some more feedback

Comment: I understand that MongoDb uses ES6 promises: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/db.js#L96 I believe that the `.d.ts` files in the DefinitelyTyped repo are not correct, so it's not an error on your side. Maybe, you can fix them and send them a pull request. (Why do you use Bluebird?)

Comment: I use Bluebird because it is ultimately the same basic syntax, but adds Promisify, and I heard on a Podcast once that it is far faster. In practise, the speed gains wouldn't make any difference for this code, but it also shouldn't make any difference at the level of types either?

Comment: I guess it shouldn't here. The main problem is that https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts is not correct. You can file an issue or try to fix it. I don't think I can offer here more help than that.